# What's the meaning of 'TRWTF '?

Tags: phrases, acronyms, catch-phrases

> TRWTF is they were running as root, at a nuclear sciences research facility!
>
> TRWTF is that the World Cup was in South Africa.

What's the detailed meaning of the above sentences?

How many catchphrases like "IMHO" in  English?
Be thankful to any advice.

Comment: @kit.yang, "How many catchphrases like "IMHO" in the common spoken English?" should be entered as a separate question on the site.

Comment: FMI: does anybody use those in spoken English? TRWTF even has more syllables than the phrase itself. And how would IMHO be pronounced?

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser Thanks for your advice.I will edit the problem soon.

Comment: @Ralph Rickenbach I have modified the questions.Thanks.

Comment: @Ralph, expressions like WTF, OMG, IMHO, BTW, etc. are spoken on my college campus. It's also not unheard of for people to say "smiley" or "angry face" in lieu of emoticons. Take from that what you will. :)

Comment: @kitukwfyer: they say those things? but that's what facial expressions are for...

Comment: @Matt For example (from a conversation a day or two ago): "So, I took my EF (engineering fundamentals) exam, and I was just like OMG. WTF do they expect me to do with a freaking *furlongs* problem?! Do you know how to convert FURLONGS into ACRES? I did not. Cries. So...I ended up just drawing Darth Vader riding Yoshi while eating a burrito. And the TA gave me 2 points for making him laugh. I was like OMGWTFBBQ smileys. Yeah, it was pretty awesome..." The OMGWTFBBQ is a little tongue-in-cheek, but that was reflecting the ridiculousness of the story, not how she was saying it.

Comment: @kitukwfyer: I LOLed :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means:

> The real "What the F***"

Which is:

> What is really bad about this, where they really blew it was...

[WTF](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/what_the_fuck) is an abbreviation in its own right and could also mean

> What in the world, what in God's name

Therefore TRWTF would express

> The reason one might exclaim "What in the world is this", is that they were running as root, at a nuclear sciences research facility.

For the origin, see [Claudiu's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/whats-the-meaning-of-trwtf/5072#5072).

Comment: "where the really blew"?

Comment: I believe that should be "where they really blew it was..."

Comment: I'm not sure the emphasis of "WTF" is (in this case or in general) that they screwed up.  It means something more like "The really shocking thing that you wouldn't have seen coming," but with a connotation that the surprise is negative.

Comment: This XKCD comic demonstrates an example of TRWTF: http://xkcd.com/463/

Answer (score 6):

[Ralph's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5066/whats-the-meaning-of-trwtf/5067#5067) has got the meaning. As to the origin... there is a website, [www.thedailywtf.com](http://www.thedailywtf.com), which has daily posts of really idiotic and messed up coding practices. Usually the story is obviously terrible in a certain way. However, people say "Well, the *real* wtf is..." meaning, the thing that is *really* messed up.. and they point out something more subtle/funny.

Comment: Usually TRWTF is the fact that the code sample is written in Visual Basic.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New  At the website Claudiu given,I saw the origin of **WTF**.`offers living examples of code that invites the exclamation 'WTF!?'" and "recounts tales of disastrous development, from project management gone spectacularly bad to inexplicable coding choices.`

Comment: @kit.yang: that website isn't really the origin of the term "WTF", just one of the places that have helped make it popular. However, users on that site may have coined "TRWTF", where it is a running joke/meme to try to come up with the wittiest or funniest "real" wtf.

Comment: TRWTF, as always, is the comments ;) (p.s. that's a quote from every comments thread on TDWTF.com)

Comment: @Matt: is that automatically inserted into each thread or something, then?